# Modify an element on-the-fly so it matches a given selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Let's say I've got element like:

```
<div class="some-class"></div>
```

and selector like:

```
#mydiv.super.another-class[some-attribute="true"]
```

---

I'd like to make my div match this selector. It would require

- Adding id `mydiv`
- Adding classes `super`, `another-class`
- Adding attribute `some-attribute` with value `true`

So final div would look like

```
<div class="some-class super another-class" id="mydiv" some-attribute="true"></div>
```

Is there any way to do something like

```
$(".some-class").makeMatch('#mydiv.super.another-class[some-attribute="true"]');
```

That would parse selector and execute steps listed above for **any** valid selector?

I know I can do some function that will parse selector and do it, but selectors can be so complex and same selector may be composed in so many different ways that I've decided to try to find some solid existing solution.

Do you know anything like that, or maybe is there any native way?

---

Edit: According to comments I'll try to explain my question in different way.

The main point of problem is:

Is it possible to parse any valid selector with javascript to know what id, what classes and what attributes is it pointing?

So we'd have like

```
var selectorData = parseSelector('#my-id.class-one.class-two[attr-one="value-one"]');
selectorData.id //my-id
selectorData.classes //class-one class-two
selectorData.attributes["attr-one"] //value
```

Because having this data about selector it's very easy to make any element match it.

Comment: This is a very interesting, if rather obscure, use case. Selectors are indeed complex, but the nature of what you're trying to do gives rise to a few interesting restrictions that can be made in order to narrow down a potential solution. For example, only feature selectors (type, ID, class and attribute) and possibly structural pseudos could be accepted. The precise implementation might be a bit broad though given that a full-blown parser may have to be written, even if the parser is restricted to handling just a single compound selector consisting of only feature selectors.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach, albeit with a somewhat naive approach, would be:

```
// create a jQuery plug-in, 'makeMatch()' and pass a selector
// string as an argument:
(function ($) {
    $.fn.makeMatch = function (selector) {
        // finding a string of one or more alphanumeric characters,
        // underscores and hyphens that starts with the '#' character,
        // using String.prototype.match() with a regular expression:
        var id = selector.match(/#[\w-]+/),
            // similar to the above, though this string starts with a
            // period (escaped with a back-slash because the period
            // is a special character in regular expressions), using
            // the 'g' (global) flag to retrieve all matching
            // sequences:
            classes = selector.match(/\.[\w-]+/g),
            // this string looks for strings starting with a '['
            // (again escaped because it's a special character) and
            // continuing until it matches a character that is *not*
            // ']':
            attributeValuePairs = selector.match(/\[[^\]]+/g);
        // if we have an 'id' sequence:
        if (id) {
            // assigning the found id sequence to the id variable
            // (preventing us from accessing a property of a null
            // object) after replacing the leading '#' character
            // with an empty string:
            id = id[0].replace(/^#/,'');
        }

        // iterating over the passed-in jQuery object, 'this' (here)
        // is the collection of nodes:
        return this.each(function () {
            // caching the current node found in the collection:
            var self = this;

            // if we have an id (it's not null):
            if (id) {
                // setting the id to that matched-id:
                self.id = id;
            }
            // if we have an array of classes:
            if (classes) {
                // adding the classes from the array, by joining
                // each class-string together with spaces and replacing
                // the period characters (though we could simply do:
                // classes.replace(/\./g,' ') instead):
                $(self).addClass(classes.join(' ').replace(/\./g, ''));
            }
            if (attributeValuePairs) {
                // creating a variable to avoid re-initialising a
                // variable within the forEach():
                var av;
                attributeValuePairs.forEach(function(avp) {
                    // replacing the initial '[' character from
                    // each element of the array with an empty string
                    // and splitting that string on the '=' character
                    // to form a two-part array (if a '=' character
                    // is found):
                    av = avp.replace(/^\[/, '').split('=');
                    // if we do have a two-part array:
                    if (av.length === 2) {
                      // setting the attribute held in 'av[0]' with
                      // the value held in 'av[1]' (after replacing
                      // any quotes held in that string):
                      self.setAttribute(av[0], av[1].replace(/"|'/g, ''));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.makeMatch = function(selector) {
    var id = selector.match(/#[\w-]+/),
      classes = selector.match(/\.[\w-]+/g),
      attributeValuePairs = selector.match(/\[[^\]]+/g);
    if (id) {
      id = id[0].replace(/^#/,'');
    }
    return this.each(function() {
      var self = this;
      if (id) {
        self.id = id;
      }
      if (classes) {
        $(self).addClass(classes.join(' ').replace(/\./g, ''));
      }
      if (attributeValuePairs) {
        var av;
        attributeValuePairs.forEach(function(avp) {
          av = avp.replace(/^\[/, '').split('=');
          if (av.length === 2) {
            self.setAttribute(av[0], av[1].replace(/"|'/g, ''));
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);


$(".some-class").makeMatch('#mydiv.super.another-class[some-attribute="true"]');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#mydiv.super.another-class[some-attribute="true"] {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: transparent url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class"></div>
```

It's worth noting, though, that I've not addressed the issue of boolean attributes/properties (such as `checked`, `selected`, etc) or the ability to add attributes without a value. This could be done, I just don't have the time, as yet, to account for all the edge-cases that might be implied by such a feature.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).
  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - "[How to create a basic [jQuery] plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)."

Comment: You'll want to create a CSS rule with the new selector - possibly combined with the `.some-class` selector - to show that the element will match this selector now.

Comment: I understand the point, and the intent, but I *really* don't want to have to do that... ;)

Comment: Having a runnable snippet seem pretty superfluous in that case :)

Comment: @BoltClock: yeah, for some reason I was under the impression that you meant in the snippet the plug-in should add the selector (no, I have no idea why I thought that). Edited and added.

Answer (score 1):

i have written you a small jquery function for that

```
$.fn.makeMatch = function(ids, classes, attr) {
    this.attr('id', ids).addClass(classes).attr(attr);
    return this;
}
```

you now just have to:

```
$('div').makeMatch('firstComesOneId', 'then classes seperated by space', {'data-arrayKey1' : 'value1', 'data-arrayKey2' : 'value2'})
```

that would output:

```
<div id="firstComesOneId" class="then classes seperated by space" data-arrayKey1="value1" data-arrayKey2="value2">
```

hope thats what you needed.

---

after the op told me this above is not the way he needs it ( althoug it works ) here is I HOPE the desired function he needs:

```
    $.fn.stringToObject = function(values) {

    var selectorData = [];

    var start_posID = values.indexOf('#') + 1;
    var end_posID = values.indexOf('.',start_posID);
    selectorData['id'] = values.substring(start_posID,end_posID);


    var classSplit = values.split('.');
    var classLength = classSplit.length -1;
    var attrSplit = values.match(/\[/g);
    var attrLength = attrSplit.length;


    var start_posClass = end_posID;
    var end_posClass = values.indexOf('[',start_posClass);
    var stringClass = values.substring(start_posClass, end_posClass);
    selectorData['classes'] = stringClass.replace(/\./g, " ");

    for (var i = 0; i <= attrLength; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            var start = values.indexOf('[') + 1;
        } else if(i == attrLength) {
            start = nextstart -1;
        } else {
            start = nextstart +2;
        }


        var end                 = values.indexOf(']',start);
        var newstring           = values.substring(start, end);
        var nextstart           = end;

        var newstringLength     = newstring.length;
        var firstPartOffset     = newstring.indexOf('=');
        var firstPart           = newstring.substring(0, firstPartOffset);
        var secondPart          = newstring.substring(firstPartOffset +1, newstringLength);

        selectorData[firstPart] = secondPart;


    };

    return selectorData;
}
```

here is how you use it:

```
var valueArray = $( "div" ).stringToObject('#mydiv.super.another-class[some-attribute1="true"][some-attribute2="truesdsda"][some-attribute3="trueasd"][some-attribute4="true"][some-attribute5="truedfg"]');

console.log(valueArray); // gives you everything
console.log(valueArray.id); // = gives you the id
console.log(valueArray.classes); // = gives you the classes
console.log(valueArray['some-attribute5']); // = gives you the value from some-attribute5
```

took me some time, i really hope that helps :)

greetings timmi

Comment: so if the element has a data attr or an id you want to get that?

Comment: i also don't get what you want exactly... you have a div with some attr and classes for instance. and you now want to get all classes and attr from that div in jquery? is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work.

```
$(".some-class").addClass('super');
$(".some-class").addClass('another-class');
$(".some-class").attr('id','myDiv');
$(".some-class").attr('some-attribute',true);
```

Comment: You've misunderstood my question. It will indeed make element match selector, but what you've done is - you've parsed selector with your brain to important element, in your mind you know what id, class and attribute is needed and you've wrote code reflecting this. I want computer to do it. So I'll only tell selector and element, and javascript will do the rest.